# Subject Alt Name certs

Tags: tls, certificates, san

Is it ok to specify subdomains in certificates that support SAN.
For example base domain is `example.com` and I want `a.example.com`, `b.example.com`, and `c.example.com` to be included? What is the primary purpose of SANs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of SAN is to specify all host names for which a certificate can be used. This also includes any subdomains a certificate should be valid for, i.e. a certificate for `example.com` will not be automatically valid for `foo.example.com` but this subdomain must be explicitly specified as valid. Entries can also be wildcards. A proper implementation will no longer look at the common name at all if DNS names are given in the SAN section.